# Nested relationships in blade in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am building my app. I have model user, review and reviewAnswer. I want to display reviewAnswers in blade, but I do not know how to get it from nested relationships, because it looks like:

```
User -> has many -> Review
Review -> Belongs to -> user

Review->hasMany->ReviewAnswer
ReviewAnswer->belongs to -> review
```

Now what can I do to display reviewAnswer in blade using something like this - $user->review->reviewAnswer->table from db

Can you help me?

Comment: Why did you mention blade here?

Comment: See the section that starts with 'If you are in a nested loop...' -
 https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#the-loop-variable

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay because i need to put data in blade

Comment: You got to put more effort in your question..Show us the code, and what you already have tried.

Comment: so you want to get all the review answers belonging to one User, right?

Comment: Check [the eloquent docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) under **Nested Eager Loading**

Answer (score 1):

If I got this correctly, you want to use [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).
Basically:

```
User extends Model {
    public function reviews() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Review');
    }
}

Review extends Model {
    public function reviewAnswers() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ReviewAnswers');
    }
}

$usersReviewAnswers = App\User::with('reviews.reviewAnswers')->get();
```